# Nuxt 3 Server API Reporting Progress back to Client

Tags: server, state, progress-bar, nuxt3

I have an Nuxt 3 Electron App with a CSV parser endpoint in the server API folder, parsing and writing a large CSV using file streams.

Given that such a request will take a while to process, I wish to report back the progress to the client for display in a custom progress bar (based on a calculated percentage from the number of parsed bytes vs total bytes in the file).

I am using the Nuxt Server API endpoint as this gives me assess to the fs and stream NodeJS modules which aren't available directly in the browser.

I know there are questions that focus on file uploads or downloads using requests.get() streams, but this is a different thing entirely from what I can make out.

In simple terms I have a HTML file selection input that (because it's an electron app) gives me access to the file path of the file/s from the browser. I'm then posting these file paths to the server endpoint to open a read and write file stream for the selected files (given that fs filestreams are not accessible in the browser).

I was thinking I could store the progress percentage in a variable that the parser endpoint updates. I could then create another endpoint that the client can pole to get updated info on progress. However, I'm unclear how I can share this variable between different endpoints.

I was hoping to use Pinia, but this cannot apparently be used on the server side as it loads after the server.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem/alternative approach?